how to reduce low frequency sound coming from a waste treatment 300m away
added 6 inch of rockwood insulation to  attic , insulate bedroom outside walls with another 4 inch wall on top of existing ,insulation basement ceiling , nothing is working  the low frequency sound still driving me nuts , help please.

Maybe a white or a pink noise machine.  For low  frequency sound you would almost need to isolate(stop from touching) the house from the ground.   This question might help with what is required.   https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/261044/reduce-low-frequency-noise-from-nearby-rail-yard-during-home-renovation-and-wall?rq=1

noise cancelling headphones can be effective at low frequencies if it's coming in your ears.

Regrettably, this is not an easy DIY project.
While blocking high-frequency sounds with insulation is easy, blocking low frequency vibration can be done a few ways:

Adding a noise barrier, either around the noise source or around your home
Elastic isolation
Adding mass to structures
Active noise cancellation

Along highways, many locales have built large sound barriers. Some work by reflecting the noise back to the highway, others use acoustic interference in a pattern in the wall to reduce noise. Some companies making these are AcoustiGuard, Noise Barrier Walls and Sound Fighter Systems. This would be a large, expensive project for a home-owner, but you might convince your community to put a sound barrier around the waste-treatment plant, using the incentive that it would increase local property value.
Where sound and vibration reduction is essential, as in a semiconductor fab, equipment or entire rooms may be supported by springs. That elastic isolation in of course not practical for a home.
Adding extra mass to walls, windows, ceiling and floor by putting in additional layers can help block sound. This is obviously expensive and takes a great amount of labor, but this might be the most practical DIY approach.
Active noise cancellation requires installing equipment to provide sound 180° out of phase with the noise, cancelling that noise in a limited area. For example, Bose, Harman and others make devices to lower noise level inside a car (and likely only effective at specific seating positions in the car). To make an office quieter, Zero Sound offers a "ZS Suppression Matrix ™", with multiple emitters providing cancellation over a larger region. Noise-cancellation for a whole room, much less the house, seems to be an expensive proposition.
You might also consider noise-cancelling headphones such as these at CNET or Rtings.com. Likely, they would not be comfortable for sleeping or use all day.
On the other hand, the house might be a good buy for someone with limited hearing, and you could move to a queiter location.
